ESLint disallow/ban `this` return type for verbosity
How do I use the ESLint no-restricted-syntax rule to disallow/ban the this keyword from being used as a return type on functions and class methods.

What do you mean by "for verbosity"? What's the actual goal with that?

@Bergi Mainly just that : TYPE looks better to me than : this

@Bergi But also, this is not a fixed type, its meaning is dependent on context, moving class methods across classes can get ugly.

"Better-looking" is relative, I prefer to express the precise semantics (which are different): inheriting a this-returning method to a subclass means it'll return a subclass instance. As for moving methods from class to class, I've never had to do that…

rules: {
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
        "error",
        "FunctionExpression[returnType.typeAnnotation.type='TSThisType']",
        "ArrowFunctionExpression[returnType.typeAnnotation.type='TSThisType']"
    ]
}

https://eslint.org/docs/v9.x/rules/no-restricted-syntax
place of discovery
